# Running npm install on fresh installation of Angular/node.js gives ENOTDIR error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package

I am trying to get started with Angular and node.js, doing their preliminary to the tour of heroes [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-01).

On a fresh install of Angular, node.js and npm, running `npm install` on their default package gets me the following after a minute or so:

```
G:\My Drive\website\first-app>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\website\first-app\node_modules\copyfiles\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\website\first-app\node_modules\copyfiles\node_modules'
```

I've tried a number of potential fixes:

- making the directory `...\first-app\node_modules\copyfiles\node_modules` myself
- running cmd with admin privileges
- checking logs for more useful info
- ensuring npm is at the latest version

At this point I'm totally stuck! Would be very grateful for any advice on what I might be able to try, or what the source of the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the approach of "doing anything random that might have some effect", I finally got this to work. Decided to post an answer in case anyone has this issue.

What worked was simply to move the project folder to my desktop and try again. Previously it was in my google drive folder. This is the first time I have issues with that.